# Problem creation VMSS with Skutypes Azure-sdk-for-java

Tags: java, azure, api, azure-sdk

I can create my VMSS with CLI with skutype : STANDARD_D2S_V3 but it's not possible on JAVA because i didn't have this type of sku. There are not V3 on Java but i use Java and i use virtualization so i need a skutype allowing virtualization. I didn't found an option for this.

I try to use another function but i didn't find any function, any type in this function allowing virtualization.

```
public static void creationVMSS(){
  VirtualMachineScaleSet vmss = azure.virtualMachineScaleSets()
    .define("name")
    .withregion(SOUTHEAST_ASIA)
    .withExistingResourceGroup(MyRG)
    .withSku(VirtualMachineScaleSetSkuTypes.STANDARD_..._v2
}
```

I want a type of VM allowing virtualization

Comment: Do you try to create a custom value for VirtualMachineSizeTypes?

Comment: it's possible to create a custom value ? Command ?

Comment: Not sure, do you use this [VirtualMachineScaleSetSkuTypes(String skuName, String skuTier)](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/java/api/com.microsoft.azure.management.compute.virtualmachinescalesetskutypes.virtualmachinescalesetskutypes?view=azure-java-stable#com_microsoft_azure_management_compute_VirtualMachineScaleSetSkuTypes_VirtualMachineScaleSetSkuTypes_String_String_)?

Comment: No, i use this VirtualMachineScaleSetSkuTypes(Sku sku), but what is this two strings ?

Comment: Just as the document shows you, the SKU name and the tier, you can understand it if you take a look at any one SKU.

Comment: I understand this strings but how can i create my sku type with only 2 strings ? It's not possible that Azure associates the string to the good sku type ??

Comment: You can follow the code in [Github](https://github.com/Azure/azure-sdk-for-java/blob/v1.3.0/azure-mgmt-compute/src/main/java/com/microsoft/azure/management/compute/VirtualMachineScaleSetSkuTypes.java/#L20) and just take a try.

Comment: thank you for your help !!! I try and i give a response but my sku type is not present...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For your issue, there truly is no STANDARD_D2S_V3 SKU list in Java SDK. But it's actually supported in Azure for VMSS. So you can use the method that provides in the Azure Java SDK [VirtualMachineScaleSetSkuTypes(String skuName, String skuTier)](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/java/api/com.microsoft.azure.management.compute.virtualmachinescalesetskutypes.virtualmachinescalesetskutypes?view=azure-java-stable#com_microsoft_azure_management_compute_VirtualMachineScaleSetSkuTypes_VirtualMachineScaleSetSkuTypes_String_String_) to create a custom SKU named STANDARD_D2S_V3, just like it shows in the [Github](https://github.com/Azure/azure-sdk-for-java/blob/v1.3.0/azure-mgmt-compute/src/main/java/com/microsoft/azure/management/compute/VirtualMachineScaleSetSkuTypes.java/#L20):

```
public static final VirtualMachineScaleSetSkuTypes STANDARD_A0 = new VirtualMachineScaleSetSkuTypes("Standard_A0", "Standard");
```